# Geopandas: Get angle at intersection between two LINESTRINGs

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have two LINESTRINGS in Geopandas, and I would like to find the angle between the two LINESTRINGS at their point of intersection.

**Note:** one line is a random walk, so I am looking for the angle at the point of intersection, not based on the start/end points of the walk.

Comment: I have wrote one implementation of the angle here https://github.com/martinfleis/momepy/blob/9af821dfaf05ab7abdde5e96e12de0e90c4481b4/momepy/utils.py#L112. To do it on the intersection I would clip the LineStrings around the intersections by a tiny buffer to get start/end points. Easier than to look for the closest existing coords.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you tried, what went wrong, and/or what you were expecting?